# How to run a deprecated snap?

Tags: snap

The play0ad snap is deprecated and has been replaced by 0ad. It won't receive further updates.

Please install 0ad and remove play0ad:

```
snap install 0ad
snap remove play0ad
```

I do want to run play0ad

Comment: Is this the game 0AD and are there any differencs between the two? 0AD is available in Ubuntu repository or through a PPA.

Comment: Yes, that very game. Apparently, Ubuntu store has a play0AD repo from the same author, albeit  deprecated.